# Determine a normal distribution given its quantile information

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution, quantile

I was wondering how I could have R tell me the **SD** (as an argument in the      **qnorm()** built in R) for a normal distribution whose 95% limit values are already known?

As an example, I know the two 95% limit values for my normal are 158, and 168, respectively. So, in  **the below R code** **SD** is shown as "x". **If** "y" (the answer of this simple **qnorm()** function) needs to be (158, 168), **then** can R tell me what should be **x**?

```
y <- qnorm(c(.025,.975), 163, x)
```

Comment: You question is unclear.  In order for us to be able to answer your question, please include a sample of your data by typing `dput(variableName)` and copying and pasting the console output into your question.  Additionally, show what your desired output should look like.  For more information on how to make a reproducible example in `R` (and make it more likely your question is answered) please view [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## A general procedure for Normal distribution

Suppose we have a Normal distribution `X ~ N(mu, sigma)`, with unknown mean `mu` and unknown standard deviation `sigma`. And we aim to solve for `mu` and `sigma`, given two quantile equations:

```
Pr(X < q1) = alpha1
Pr(X < q2) = alpha2
```

We consider standardization: `Z = (X - mu) / sigma`, so that

```
Pr(Z < (q1 - mu) / sigma) = alpha1
Pr(Z < (q2 - mu) / sigma) = alpha2
```

In other words,

```
(q1 - mu) / sigma = qnorm(alpha1)
(q2 - mu) / sigma = qnorm(alpha2)
```

The RHS is explicitly known, and we define `beta1 = qnorm(alpha1)`, `beta2 = qnorm(alpha2)`. Now, the above simplifies to a system of 2 linear equations:

```
mu + beta1 * sigma = q1
mu + beta2 * sigma = q2
```

This system has coefficient matrix:

```
1  beta1
1  beta2
```

with determinant `beta2 - beta1`. The only situation for singularity is `beta2 = beta1`. As long as the system is non-singular, we can use `solve` to solve for `mu` and `sigma`.

Think about what the singularity situation means. `qnorm` is strictly monotone for Normal distribution. So `beta1 = beta2` is as same as `alpha1 = alpha2`. But this can be easily avoided as it is under your specification, so in the following I will not check singularity.

Wrap up above into an estimation function:

```
est <- function(q, alpha) {
  beta <- qnorm(alpha)
  setNames(solve(cbind(1, beta), q), c("mu", "sigma"))
  }
```

Let's have a test:

```
x <- est(c(158, 168), c(0.025, 0.975))
#        mu      sigma 
#163.000000   2.551067 

## verification
qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975), x[1], x[2])
# [1] 158 168
```

---

We can also do something arbitrary:

```
x <- est(c(1, 5), c(0.1, 0.4))
#      mu    sigma 
#5.985590 3.890277 

## verification
qnorm(c(0.1, 0.4), x[1], x[2])
# [1] 1 5
```