# Solving (determining) a function at a point in R

Tags: r, function, statistics, normal-distribution

In my **below R code,** I was wondering how I could find out what is **rh1** when **y == 0.5**?

Note that **y** uses `atanh(rh1)`, which can be converted back to **rh1** using `tanh()`.

```
rh1 <- seq(-1, 0.1, by = 0.001)
y <- pnorm(-0.13, atanh(rh1), 0.2)
plot(rh1, y, type = "l")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Analytical solution**

For a normal distribution `X ~ N(mu, 0.2)`. We want to find `mu`, such that `Pr (X < -0.13) = y`.

Recall your previous question and my answer over there: [Determine a normal distribution given its quantile information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41132804/4891738). Here we have something simpler, as there is only one unknown parameter and one piece of quantile information.

Again, we start by standardization:

```
   Pr {X < -0.13} = y
=> Pr { [(X - mu) / 0.2] < [(-0.13 - mu) / 0.2] } = y
=> Pr { Z < [(-0.13 - mu) / 0.2] } = y    # Z ~ N(0,1)
=> (-0.13 - mu) / 0.2 = qnorm (y)
=> mu = -0.13 - 0.2 * qnorm (y)
```

Now, let `atanh(rh1) = mu  =>  rh1 = tanh(mu)`, so in short, the analytical solution is:

```
tanh( -0.13 - 0.2 * qnorm (y) )
```

---

**Numerical solution**

It is a root finding problem. We first build the following function `f`, and we aim to find its root, i.e., the `rh1` so that `f(rh1) = 0`.

```
f <- function (rh1, y) pnorm(-0.13, atanh(rh1), 0.2) - y
```

The simplest root finding method is bisection method, implemented by `uniroot` in R. I recommend you reading [Uniroot solution in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38964900/4891738) for how we should work with it in general.

```
curve(f(x, 0.5), from = -1, to = 0.1); abline (h = 0, lty = 2)
```

We see there is a root between `(-0.2, 0)`, so:

```
uniroot(f, c(-0.2, 0), y = 0.5)$root
# [1] -0.129243
```

Comment: `uniroot` actually does something a little fancier than bisection (Brent's method: 'The function makes use of the "gold section" procedure combined with the parabolic interpolation', from http://www.netlib.org/c/brent.shar ). Not that it would matter for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is monotonic so you can just create the inverse function.

```
rh1 <- seq(-1,.1,by=.001)
y <- pnorm(-.13,atanh(rh1),.2)

InverseFun = approxfun(y, rh1)
InverseFun(0.5)
[1] -0.1292726
```